# How to install package in R

Tags: r, k-means, powerbi

I want to install package in R : `nloptr`, `seriation`, `pbkrtest`, `NbClust`, `cluster`, `car`, `scales`, `fpc`, `mclust`, `apcluster`, `vegan` to use it on my powerbi for k means clustering.

I already install R 3.3.1 in my windows. I open my R like this:

[image: R command prompt]

I already tried use two commands to install packages like this:

```
install.packages("D:/Skripsi/PowerBI-visuals-clustering-kmeans-master.zip', lib='C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1',repos = NULL)

install.packages.zip("D:/Skripsi/PowerBI-visuals-clustering-kmeans-master.zip", repos = NULL)
```

but I get an error

> no function install.package.zip or no such file.

my package location : `D:\Skripsi\PowerBI-visuals-clustering-kmeans-master`

I want to use this package : https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-clustering-kmeans or do I have to install one by one and how to install package in R? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a "*normal*" package:

```
install.packages("NAME_OF_YOUR_PACKAGE")
```

It it is a "*bioconductor*" package:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(NAME_OF_YOUR_PACKAGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository on GitHub you link to is not in the valid R package structure and thus not installable as such. You are best downloading the files, extracting them locally and sourcing (using function `source`, see `help("source")`) any R scripts you may want to use.

As for the rest, there is no function called `install.packages.zip` that would come with base R installation. When I install packages from local zip files (rarely, though), I use

```
install.packages("/path/to/zipfile.zip", repos = NULL)
```

and it appears to work fine. As already said, this won't work for your "PowerBI-visuals-clustering-kmeans-master.zip".

To install the packages you mention, you should do something along the lines of

```
install.packages(c("nloptr", "seriation", "pbkrtest", "NbClust", "cluster", "car", "scales", "fpc", "mclust", "apcluster", "vegan"))
```

Comment: thanks it's installing the package :). hope it works in powerbi .

Comment: still have a  problem at powerbi :). hmm do u know the use of GitHub zip ? because i install similar package in GitHub too for python(tweepy). i could install it in my python. but i still confuse the file in GitHub or how to install it in R.

Comment: @DeanHuang I address this in my answer. The code you refer to in the link is not a valid R package that could be installed through `install.packages`.